# Add dollar sign to a number in filter?

Tags: formatting

I have a filter where it displays the min and max price but it does not display the dollar sign.

for example

Min Price - 100

Max Price - 200

I would like for it to display

Min Price - $100

Max Price - $200

I have tried to add echo '$'; but have come up empty handed.

Appreciate any help!

```
<input type="number" class="wpc-filters-range-min" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $minName ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $min ); ?>" step="<?php echo esc_attr( $filter['step'] ); ?>" data-min="<?php echo esc_attr( $absMin ); ?>" />
```